# Toggle html content with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

With this code (JS)

```
<script>
  function changeText(element){
        element.innerHTML = "<span class='icon-remove3'>Content icon-remove3</span> Eliminar del pack";
         element.style.background = "#CCC";

    }   
</script>
```

I can change the content of the following label:

```
<label class="anadir_producto" for="additional_buy_{$packcontent.id_product}" onclick="changeText(this);" id="anadir"><span class="icon-4">Content Icon 4</span>Añadir al pack</label>
```

but the problem comes when I am trying to switch back to "Añadir al pack", since it does not toggle back.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/U8yY8/3/)

Any clue?

Comment: Why would it toggle back? You have no code that does so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizing jquery library ,

Try

```
(function (_o) {
  $("label.anadir_producto").on("click", function (e) {
    $(this).html(function (i, o) {
       return ( o === _o 
              ? "<span class='icon-remove3'>"
                + "Content icon-remove3"
                + "</span>Eliminar del pack"
              : _o );
    });
    return ( $("span", this).is(".icon-remove3") 
           ? $(this).css("background", "#ccc") 
           : $(this).css("background", "transparent") );
    })
}($("label.anadir_producto").html()));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/5U27a/

Answer (score 2):

You're never setting the original text back. Something like this is probably the simplest next step:

```
function changeText(element){
  if (element.innerHTML.indexOf("icon-4") >= 0) {
    element.innerHTML = "<span class='icon-remove3'></span> Eliminar del pack";
  } else {
    element.innerHTML = "<span class='icon-4'>Content Icon 4</span>Añadir al pack";
  }
  element.style.background = "#CCC";
}
```

See how we check what the text is, before setting the new contents? That way you can toggle between the values.

There are a lot of cleaner ways to do this, such as checking the class of the `span` using the DOM instead of a string comparison.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, use jQuery. :-)

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/U8yY8/5/

```
$('.anadir_producto').toggle(function() {
    $(this).html('<span class="icon-remove3">Content icon-remove3</span> Eliminar del pack');
}, function() {
    $(this).html('<span class="icon-4">Content Icon 4</span>Añadir al pack');
});
```

Notice that I've removed your `onclick` property from the HTML. It's usually better to keep things separate.

Comment: But your code misses the background color from the clicked event :(

Comment: True, but that would be trivial to do with a toggled class.

Answer (score 1):

Else part needs to be handled to switch to original content

```
function changeText(element){    
    if(!element.isFlipped){
        element.innerHTML = "<span class='icon-remove3'></span> Eliminar del pack";
        element.style.background = "#CCC";
        element.isFlipped = true;
    }
    else{
        element.innerHTML = "<span class='icon-4'>Content Icon 4</span>Añadir al pack";
        element.style.background = 'none';
        element.isFlipped = false;
     }
    }
```